# How to override route in .ASP.NET Core 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-routing

I want to override route in ASP.NET Core 5

I tried this one but it is not working

```
var lastExistingRoute= routeBuilder.Routes.FirstOrDefault(x => ((Route)x).Name == "HomePage");
            routeBuilder.Routes.Remove(lastExistingRoute);
            routeBuilder.MapRoute("HomePage", "",
                new { controller = "CustomPage", action = "Homepage", });


  var lastDownloadRoute=routeBuilder.Routes.FirstOrDefault(x => ((Route)x).Name == "GetDownload");
            routeBuilder.Routes.Remove(lastDownloadRoute);
            routeBuilder.MapRoute("GetDownload", "download/getdownload/{guid}/{agree?}",
                new { controller = "AzTechProduct", action = "GetPayed", });
```

Comment: Do you meet any error or exception? Generally, we use the [Routing middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and use the UseRouting() and UseEndpoints() to configure the route in Asp.net core 5, but from your code it seems that you want to use the UseMvc() method to configure the route, right? If that is the case, you should disable the endpoint routing in the ConfigureServices method: `services.AddMvc(Op => { Op.EnableEndpointRouting = false; });`

Comment: @ZhiLv - Simple add new route is worked for me. This code reference was as per .Net Core 3.10

         endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute("NewCheckout", "onepagecheckout",
                      new { controller = "NewCheckout", action = "OnePageCheckout" });

and good thing is it not throwing any exception even registering with same routename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created same route with high different display order is worked for me

And good this is it not throwing any exception on inserting new route with the same name

```
 public void RegisterRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder)
        {
           
            endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute("NewCheckout", "onepagecheckout",
                      new { controller = "NewCheckout", action = "OnePageCheckout" });
                    
        }

       
            return string.Empty;
        }

    public int Priority
        {
            get
            {
                return 100;
            }
        }
    }
```